# Fatal error: Call to a member function collect() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 1013

Tags: fatal-error

we are getting this error in frontend of the site.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function collect() on a non-object in /var/www/html/sitenanme/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 1013
```

This is complete code : http://pastebin.com/KkHCm0zG

''This is the code from  Address.php line 1000 to 1030."

'

```
public function getTotalModels()
{
        return $this->getTotalCollector()->getRetrievers();
    }

    /**
     * Collect address totals
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
     */
    public function collectTotals()
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_before', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
        foreach ($this->getTotalCollector()->getCollectors() as $model) {
            $model->collect($this);
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_after', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address totals as array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTotals()
    {
        foreach ($this->getTotalCollector()->getRetrievers() as $model) {
            $model->fetch($this);
        }
        return $this->_totals;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have custom totals collector you may have a typo in it.
In your config.xml that is translated by nodes `<sales><quote><totals><{custom_total}>`.
The best way to debug that is to see which `$model` is called when this error is triggered with a `Zend_Debug::dump(get_class($model));` that give you a hint about the total collector.

Comment: Its very difficult for me to debug. are you asking that am i using any extension ? is there any possible to give me the code need to be add in that file

Comment: i added like this :

Comment: public function collectTotals()
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_before', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
        foreach ($this->getTotalCollector()->getCollectors() as $model) {
            $model->collect($this);
   
   Zend_Debug::dump(get_class($model));
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_after', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
        return $this;

Comment: now its displaying like this : http://prntscr.com/9elo4f did i misplaced the code ?